# xhost unable to open display ":0.0" or any hostname - red hat oracle 11.2 client installation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, x11, redhat, xorg

I'm installing oracle 11.2 client in a red hat 7 machine but i'm stucked in this step:

**xhost fully_qualified_remote_host_name**

The error that appears is the following:

**unable to open display ":0.0"**

The ":0.0" is because the environment variable is set to be ":0.0". I tried to modify to the ip and hostname provided by the "hostname" command but none work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you connecting to the server - through an X-Windows client? Some other client, like PuTTY, and if so does that support X-Windows pass through? If you're connecting from a PC do you have an X-Windows client installed and running? DISPLAY should be set to your client IP, not the server IP, if they are different. You may want to look at a silent install; assuming you actually need the full client and not just the instant client, which is much simpler to install.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AlexPoole. 
I'm using putty terminal to access the machine. What do you mena be silent install? how can I run it? thanks